# Simplifying table into div

Tags: html, html-table

```
<table border="1" width="800">
<tr>
<td colspan="2">1</td>
<td colspan="2">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I'm having some troubles simplifying this table into some div tags.. Help?

Comment: Can you provide some of your attempts?

Answer (score 0):

A very simple example would be:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="col-4">
      1
     </div>
  <div class="col-4">
      1
     </div> 
    <div class="col-2">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      1
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {width:800px;}
.col-2, .col-4 {float:left;}
.col-4 {width:400px;}
.col-2 {width:200px;}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eR6g3/

Comment: If I want to add more cells, do I have to repeat the divs or I have to change the code?

Comment: You can repeat the divs